# delegating work in constructor vs method

Tags: php, oop, constructor, initialization

I guess this might be a silly question, but I cant wrap my head over it.

So I have some code which looks like so:

```
$process = new ProcessTree();
$process->start();
```

and the class processTree is:

```
class ProcessTree()
{
    public function __construct()
    {} //dummy constructor...
}

public function start()
{
   $this->init();
   $this->doThis();
   $this->doThat();
   //etc...
}
```

So I guess my question is about the dummy constructor. According to good design, should the constructor not do something? Or even, shouldn't the body of `start()` be inside `__construct()` instead?

Comment: If every time you call the class, you immediately call that method, call it in the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

In general the constructor should not do "too much" because that would violate the Single Responsibility Principle: the constructor's responsibility is to prepare the object for use, so that's its actions should be limited to.

Of course there will be exceptions to all kinds of rules. For example, the constructor of [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php) initializes a database connection, which it's not really required to do. But in the context of `PDO` this makes sense because:

- You will always want to make that connection (and sooner rather than later)
- There is always a real possibility that the connection will not be successful (so by having the constructor connect and throw on failure you can check for this conveniently)
- If the PDO constructor didn't connect or throw then all the other methods would have to be ready to do the same. But PDO's error reporting strategy can be switched to return codes; in this scenario you would be forced to sprinkle "connection failed" logic throughout the code. That would be a really unfortunate outcome, but it's prevented once and for all by connecting in the constructor.

But as a rule of thumb, whenever in doubt don't go off doing things in the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use constructor if you don't really need it. I don't think it's a best practice just to put an empty constructor.

You should also don't move code from `start()` to constructor. Constructor should only help to initialize object (for example set some properties) and if you want to do some actions you should simple run those methods or create wrapper method (as you did) to run multiple methods at once.

Of course we don't know what you do in `init()`, `doThis()` and `doThat()` methods. If they do actions that are always necessary to use other object's method, you can move them into contructor, but as I said we don't know what's code in them.

Comment: The functions called are just performing some business logic implementation, the details of which really does not influence the question. Thank you for your answer!